# RedirectToAction is changing the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My call to `RedirectToAction` is acting like `RedirectToActionPermanent`. That is, the URL is being changed, rather than simply displaying a different view.

> **Edit**: Now that I think about it, `RedirectToAction` *typically* acts as a permanent redirect. As in, this is probably the correct behavior. In the below code, if the `ModelState` is valid, the user is given a 302 redirect back to the index. But then, what's the point of `RedirectToActionPermanent`?

The redirects are for HTTP errors. I have my Web.config set to point errors to certain action methods in `HttpErrorsController`. This works perfectly, including showing a temporary redirect, as expected. (`https://localhost/ThisPageDoesntExist` shows error page but the URL remains the same)
Returning an `HttpStatusCodeResult` or throwing an `HttpException` both work as expected.

However, if I try to do a temporary redirect to an error action method by using `RedirectToAction`, the view is still displayed properly, but the URL changes, e.g. `https://localhost/HttpErrors/404`.

HttpErrorsController.cs

```
private ViewResult ErrorView(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string shortDesc, string longDesc)
{
    Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
    return View("HttpError", new HttpErrorViewModel(httpStatusCode, shortDesc, longDesc));
}
[ActionName("404")]
public ActionResult Error404()
{
    return ErrorView(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found",
        "The requested resource could not be found.");
}
// Other identical methods for each error
```

ItemController.cs

```
public ActionResult HttpError(HttpStatusCode status)
{
    return RedirectToAction(((int)status).ToString(), "HttpErrors");
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ItemViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return HttpError(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Items.Add(pm);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return PartialView("_Create", viewModel);
}
```

Since writing the above, I've realized I'm probably better off just throwing an `HttpException`, so that it also gets caught by ELMAH, but I'm still quite confused by the behavior described above.

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToAction method sends a 302 response back to the browser with the `location` header value which the new url and the browser will make a totally new http GET request to this new url. So what you see is the expected behavior.

If you want not do the redirect, but want to keep the url as it is, do not do return a RedirectResult, return a view result as needed.

`RedirectToActionPermanent` method sends a 301 Moved Permanently response back to the client. This is usually useful when you are moving one page to another (killing an old page and creating a new one with different url) of your site and wants the client to know it so that they can  the calling code to use the new url in future. Think about google search engine changing the links to your new page and showing that in the search result.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after posting that `RedirectToAction` always does this. See my edit, regarding that. As for returning a view directly, I thought about that, but I don't know how else to call that action method from another controller. And returning `View("HttpError")` right in `ItemController` would defeat the point.

Comment: You can use a custom error handler attribute (inherit from `HandleErrorAttribute` which handles your errors and in the `OnException` method, you can return whatever response you want.

Comment: As far as I know, you still have to specify the view yourself with that.

Comment: Yes. You can  to specify what result you want to send. It could be anything, a view result, a redirect result etc

Comment: The only way I see to do that and retain my current `HttpErrorsController` is to return a `new HttpErrorsController().Error[status code here]()`, which is... janky.

Comment: I'm having trouble matching up a method parameter, say `404`, with a method, say `Error404()`. I'd like to be able to call the same method but provide and code it will would call the correct method given the code. That's what made me use `RedirectToAction` in the first place.